# Turbolinks loading content before css/images

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, laravel, turbolinks

I'm using Turbolinks in my laravel App, the problem I'm encountering now is when I switch view, the content is loaded before the CSS and images and it causes an awkward display of HTML before quickly switching to full view with is bad for UX. How can I fix this, probably by ensuring turbolinks only switches once it has loaded all CSS and images first?

====EDIT====

I've been able to uncover this much

We are routing from there to the login page:

```
@extends('./layouts/base')
@section('meta')
@section('title', 'Become a Tuper Seller')
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = " {{ asset('fonts/material-icon/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css')}} "> 
@endsection
@section('body')
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = " {{ mix('css/auth.css')}} ">
    <div class = "auth-form">
     <div class="main">

        <!-- Sign up form -->
        <section class="signup">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="signup-content">
                    <div class="signup-form">
                        <h2 class="form-title">Create A Consumer Account</h2>
                        <form method="POST" class="register-form" id="register-form">
                        @csrf
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label>
                                <input type="text" name="username" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" value = "{{ old('username')}}"/>
                            </div>
                            @error("username")
                                <div class = "alert alert-danger"> {{ $message }}</div>
                            @enderror
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email"><i class="zmdi zmdi-email"></i></label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" value = "{{ old('email')}}" id="email" placeholder="Your Email"/>
                            </div>
                            @error('email')
                                <div class = "alert alert-danger"> {{ $message }}</div>
                            @enderror
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="telephone"><i class="zmdi zmdi-phone"></i></label>
                                <input type="number" value = "{{ old('telephone') }}"name="telephone" id="telephone" placeholder="Telephone"/>
                            </div>
                            @error("telephone")
                                <div class = "alert alert-danger"> {{ $message }}</div>
                            @enderror
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i></label>
                                <input type="password" name="password" value = "{{ old('password') }}"id="pass" placeholder="Password"/>
                            </div>
                            @error('password')
                                <div class = "alert alert-danger"> {{ $message }}</div>
                            @enderror
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password_confirmation"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock-outline"></i></label>
                                <input type="password" value = "{{ old('password_confirmation')}}" name="password_confirmation" id="re_pass" placeholder="Repeat your password"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="agree-term" id="agree-term" class="agree-term" />
                                <label for="agree-term" class="label-agree-term"><span><span></span></span>I agree all statements in  <a href="#" class="term-service">Terms of service</a></label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-button">
                                <input type="submit" name="signup" id="signup" class="form-submit" value="Register"/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="signup-image">
                        <figure><img src=" {{ asset('img/tuper_logo.jpg')}} " alt="sing up image"></figure>
                        <a href=" {{ route('seller_register')}} " class="signup-image-link">I want to be a seller</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- Sing in  Form -->
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I've noticed that replacing the mix(auth.css) in the login page with inline style tags and pasting the mix file fixes this error but this is not a suitable way of accomplishing this.

Comment: The whole point of turbolinks is that the head tag does not reload when you switch to a new view only the body tag is loaded. The css should be there already. It is hard to tell what is going wrong in your case because you do not show any code.

Answer (score 0):

Well ive found a pretty neat solution. Since the css lag is caused by the link tag and since it works well when i paste the required css into style tags, i can replace by link tag with

```
<style>
{{  file_get_contents(asset('css/auth.css'))}}
</style>
```

This way it dumps the css as content instead of hyper referencing it which erradicates the dumbass delay. Also the mix helper wont work here if mix.version() is set in your webpack.mix.js because of the cache hashing.
But i dont imagine it will be a problem since there will be no cache of the css.